# tfs build definition for ios application using xcode: Failed to add the temporary keychain to the keychains search path

Tags: ios, xcode, tfs

this is the console output

```
/usr/bin/security list-keychain -d user -s

"/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"

[command]/usr/bin/security list-keychain -d user -s 

/Users/dev/Downloads/VSTS-2.134/_work/1/s/_xcodetasktmp.keychain 

/Library/Keychains/System.keychain

 [command]/usr/bin/security list-keychain -d user

 "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"

 ##[error]Failed to add the temporary keychain to the keychains search path.
```

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share your build definition?

Comment: i am using tfs version:Version 15.117.27414.0

Comment: How's your build definition like? Could you share a screenshot of your build definition?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: we found a work around by importing the certs into the system.key chain, instead of using file contents option we used identifiers option in the build step